# How to rotate all images in a directory with imagemagick?

Tags: shell-script, wildcards, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I want to rotate all the images in a directory that match a pattern.

So far I have:

```
for file in `ls /tmp/p/DSC*.JPG`; do
  convert $file -rotate 90 file+'_rotated'.JPG
done
```

but that gives no output?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are quite a few issues with your code. First of all, you are parsing ls which is a [Bad Idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). You also need to refer to the variable as `$file` as you point out and you should also quote it so it won't break on spaces. You are declaring `num` but it is never used. A safer way would be:

```
find /tmp/p/ -name "DSC*.JPG" | while IFS= read -r file; do
  convert "$file" -rotate 90 "$file"_rotated.JPG
done
```

This will still have problems if your files contain newlines but at least will not break if your path contains spaces.

If the files are all in the same directory, it can be further simplified using globbing. You can also use parameter expansion to create `foo_rotated.JPG1` instead of `foo.JPG_rotated.JPG`:

```
for file in /tmp/p/DSC*.JPG; do
  convert "$file" -rotate 90 "${file%.JPG}"_rotated.JPG
done
```

Comment: Your method will create `original_filename.JPG_rotated.JPG"`. adding `"${file%.JPG}"_rotated.JPG`  will be more appropriate imho. Cheers!

Comment: @val0x00ff absolutely (and I upvoted your answer which suggests that). I just repeated the exact thing the OP was doing fixing the more glaring errors.

Comment: cool! I just modified your command a little.

Answer (score 28):

`mogrify -rotate 90 *.jpg`
The better One-Liner for rotating all images with *imagemagick*

`mogrify -rotate 90 /tmp/p/DSC*.JPG`
will infact rotate all `.JPG` beginning with `DSC` in the `p` directory

**Mogrify** (part of imagemagick) differs from `Convert` in that it modifies the original file
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php

Comment: Not true. Mogrify "is similar to magick convert except that the original image file is overwritten (unless you change the file suffix with the -format option) with any changes you request".

Answer (score 11):

A simple method using PE (Parameter Expansion) is

```
for f in /tmp/p/DSC*.JPG
do
  convert -rotate 90 "$f" "${f%.JPG}"_converted.JPG
done
```

Comment: It should be noted that there's nothing `bash` specific in there, it's perfectly standard POSIX sh syntax.

Answer (score 6):

[Do not parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and the `ls` is not required here. Furthermore, you should quote your variables in case they contain spaces.

```
for file in *.JPG; do
  convert -rotate 90 "$file" rotated_"$file"
done
```

Comment: _space..._ or tabs, or newline or asterisk or question mark or square bracket...

Answer (score 6):

Not an imagemagic solution, but

```
sips -r 90 *.JPG
```

will rotate all images ending in .JPG 90 degrees. It's a good one liner.

Comment: fwiw, this overwrites the original images.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to refer to the file as `$file`, i.e.

```
for file in `ls /tmp/p/DSC*.JPG`; do
  convert $file -rotate 90 $file+'_rotated'.JPG
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy/paste this code in ubuntu, and save it as "rotate.sh"

```bsh
#!/bin/bash -e

CUR_DIR=`pwd`
cd "${1}"

for file in *.jpg; do
    convert "${file}" -rotate 90 "${file}";
done

cd CUR_DIR
```

After saving this file, run it from terminal using `./rotate.sh folder_containing_images`